# How to make phpMyAdmin save the alignments in Designer view

Tags: phpmyadmin

This annoying thing happens every simple refresh I do.

What happens is that while I arrange tables in the Designer View, if by any chance I need to do any change, relation ( whatever operation ), when the page is refreshed, the alignment of the tables is not saved.

Is there any possibility of having that saved because I don't find anything regarding this on google, and it would definitely be something I could make use of since there are databases with quite a few tables which I need to explain the flow for, when having to do with new employees.

I know I can save the design into a PDF, or take a print, but some databases are pretty big and I can't really print it if it's not zoomed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to have the [phpMyAdmin configuration storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables) database set up (which used to be called 'pmadb'). At least the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']` table needs to exist and be configured in `config.inc.php`.

Then, on the Designer page, you need to click "Save page" (or "Save page as") from the expanding menu:

[image: Save page menu]

You'll have to give it a name to save it, but that's just for your reference. When you return to that page in Designer, it should automatically load that saved layout. Note that you can save more than one layout and switch them from the "Open page" menu item.