# Why designer page disappears in PhpMyAdmin after new Windows installation & DB import?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I exported my database with a saved Designer page, but after reinstalling windows and xampp, then  importing my DB in a new one, the DB is imported successfully, but my tables are scattered again in Designer view, and no sign of my Designer page anywhere! how to solve this?

Comment: Database backups rarely include positions on a designer. You need to verify if the backup contains this information in the first place

Comment: how to verify? @Shadow

Comment: Open the backup file in any text editor

Comment: what should I look for in the text file? sorry I am not an expert @Shadow

Comment: Anything that indicates positions on the screen. But as I said, if you just took a abckup of a database, then thus information is unlikely to be there.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. do you know of any method I could export my designer view and import it anytime again? @Shadow

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try to find an answer by searching rather than asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254762/how-to-make-phpmyadmin-save-the-alignments-in-designer-view

Comment: i did yes :) @Shadow, and the link is not what i am looking for. nothing on the web is relevant to my search so i came here trying to find help. thanks for sharing your perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Designer layout is usually saved in the "phpmyadmin" database (or whatever you've defined as your phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage, see for instance https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_table_coords).

If you have a backup or sql dump of the old phpmyadmin database you can import that database or just that table in to your new installation.